# How to impersonate Citrix desktop login

Tags: impersonation, citrix

I am trying to build a load testing application that tests communication with a citrix published application. To do this, I need to spin up multiple instances of the citrix app as different users. However, I cannot seem to find any good documentation or examples of this anywhere.

What I have tried:

- running `PNAgent.exe using /Qlaunch "Published App"` as the impersonated user. This works, but spins up a version of PNAMain (the management utility), which is then used for all subsequent calls (so the PNAgent opens as the impersonated user, but hands off to PNAMain, which uses that first user)
- running `WFCRun32 "Published App" /username:UN /password:PW`, but I get an error along the lines of a corrupt ICA file that is missing the `ApplicationServer section`.

I think the WCFRun32 sounds promising, but I cannot figure out how to set up the parameters appropriately. Does anybody have any experience with using these programmatically, or can point me to more elaborate documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Access Gateway programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193791/accessing-access-gateway-programmatically)